# Using regenerator runtime with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to `require` the regeneratorRuntime object so that it's globally available, so my Node.js code will work with any async functions / generators babel transpiles for me anywhere in my application.  `regenerator` was installed via npm `npm install regenerator`.

My question is, why does this code

```
require('regenerator/runtime');

console.log(typeof regenratorRuntime);
if (typeof regenratorRuntime === 'object'){
    console.log(typeof regenratorRuntime.wrap);
    console.log(typeof regenratorRuntime.awrap);
    console.log(typeof regenratorRuntime.async);
    console.log(typeof regenratorRuntime.mark);
}
```

not work as expected, leading to an undefined being logged, while replacing the first line with

```
global.regenratorRuntime = require('regenerator/runtime');
```

leads to expected results.

Looking in the runtime file I see this code

```
runtime = global.regeneratorRuntime = inModule ? module.exports : {};
```

in an IIFE with this expression passed in as `global`

```
(
  // Among the various tricks for obtaining a reference to the global
  // object, this seems to be the most reliable technique that does not
  // use indirect eval (which violates Content Security Policy).
  typeof global === "object" ? global :
  typeof window === "object" ? window :
  typeof self === "object" ? self : this
);
```

which I would expect to properly set up `regenratorRuntime` on the global object.

I don't mind manually setting `global.regenratorRuntime`, but I would like to understand why it's necessary.  It seems as though code Node executes from a `require` statement may be acting differently than I assumed.

As an ancillary matter, can anyone point out what the `self` check is checking for?

Comment: `self` does exist in workers, where `window` does not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does set

```
global.regeneratorRuntime
//          ^
```

not

```
global.regenratorRuntime
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It seems a decade of experience isn't enough to prevent such foolishness :-|